# Min and max zoom Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scrollview, zooming

I've got problems with max and min zoom on my xcode project. I can't figure out how to add this. I've searched around on the internet to try and solve this, but none of the codes i have tried works. Please help :) Thanks!

Here's what i got so far to enable my zooming:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {




@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myDetailedImageView: UIImageView!


var myDetailedImageName: String?
var nameString: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func minscale () {

    }


    scrollView.delegate = self

    self.myDetailedImageView.image = UIImage(named: myDetailedImageName!)

}


func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {



    return myDetailedImageView
}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 /*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little     preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Here's my image problem:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the zoom like this.
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {




@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var myDetailedImageView: UIImageView!


var myDetailedImageName: String?
var nameString: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10
    scrollView.delegate = self

    self.myDetailedImageView.image = UIImage(named: myDetailedImageName!)

}


func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {



    return myDetailedImageView
}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 /*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little     preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

Normally that should do it.